# Why forms give Required permissions error while the permission exists in appsscript.json?

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, authorization, google-forms

I have an `OnSubmit()` method which is called on form submission. Every now and then I receive an email which reports required permissions are not given:

Your script, Alohi Invitation Request, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.

```
12/22/18 10:47 AM       onSubmit        You do not have permission to call FormApp.getActiveForm. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.currentonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms)    formSubmit
```

I have already added permissions to `appsscript.json`:

```
{
  "timeZone": "A-SAMPLE-TIMEZONE",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ]
}
```

Here I have provided `forms` permission, but `Google` complains about the permission. Why is it like that?

---

**EDIT-1:**

The form project has access to the followings:

[image]

---

**EDIT-2:**
It seems a bug so I filed an issue in `Google` issue tracker:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121420495

Comment: @TheMaster I removed the trigger and added it again, but nothing opened to reauthorize the app. I hope re-adding the trigger solve the problem.

Comment: @TheMaster there is no `connected apps` section in the provided link, it goes to `my account` page

Comment: @TheMaster please have a look at the `EDIT-1` section.

Comment: Seems it has all the permissions. Check your Executions(view>executions>clear filters). Is it possible someone else ran your script?

Comment: @TheMaster the type of column displays `trigger` for the one that `required permission email` has been sent. It seems like a bug

Comment: @TheMaster thank you for the time, I have filed an issue.

Comment: Remove the oauthScopes scopes from the appsscript.json file, and run a function from the code editor in order to force an authorization request.  There should be a permission to allow the script to run when you are not present.  That's for the "On Submit" trigger.  You're not present when the "On Form" submit trigger fires. 
 Approve the permissions, and then look at the scopes required by clicking the "File" menu, then "Project properties" and the scopes tag.  I noticed that you don't have the scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp`  in your appsscript.json file.

Comment: @SandyGood thank you for the suggestion, I have added `script.scriptapp` to list of scopes and it again prompted for review permissions. Good to note that first I removed `oauthScopes` section and reran the script but no permission request dialog opened after running `onSubmit` function in script editor. Then I added `script.scriptapp`